# Have any Pokemon that were unavailable until Pokebank received Base stat changes?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I mean,did pokemon that were unavailable before pokebank was released(e.g Zekrom) receive any stat changes?

Comment: I know Butterfree did (gained 10 in SpAtk), but that was available pre-Bank

Comment: But thanks for trying anyway.I know that the 2 questions I asked are hard to answer so sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any Pokémon in XY with changed base stats that require Bank to obtain - all of the ones that were changed are obtainable in XY in one way or another. The full list is below:

### **Generation 1: 14**

- Butterfree (+10 Special Attack)
- Beedrill (+10 Attack)
- Pidgeot (+10 Speed)
- Pikachu (+10 Defense, +10 Special Defense)
- Raichu (+10 Speed)
- Nidoqueen (+10 Attack)
- Nidoking (+10 Attack)
- Clefable (+10 Special Attack)
- Wigglytuff (+10 Special Attack)
- Vileplume (+10 Special Attack)
- Poliwrath (+10 Attack)
- Alakazam (+10 Special Defense)
- Victreebel (+10 Special Defense)
- Golem (+10 Attack)

### **Generation 2: 4**

- Ampharos (+10 Defense)
- Bellossom (+10 Defense)
- Azumarill (+10 Special Attack)
- Jumpluff (+10 Special Defense)

### **Generation 3: 2**

- Beautifly (+10 Special Attack)
- Exploud (+10 Special Defense)

### **Generation 4: 2**

- Staraptor (+10 Special Defense)
- Roserade (+10 Defense)

### **Generation 5: 7**

- Stoutland (+10 Attack)
- Unfezant (+10 Attack)
- Gigalith (+10 Special Defense)
- Seismitoad (+10 Attack)
- Leavanny (+10 Special Defense)
- Scolipede (+10 Attack)
- Krookodile (+10 Defense)

Source: [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/updatedstats.shtml)